# How to create an arraylist object from substrings in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

It is necessary that I create a `String[]` with 5 strings, each of these strings carries multiple substrings with data separated by commas, I must convert this array of int into `ArrayList` to section the sub strings in this order: the numbers '1, 2, 3, 4, 5' are student ID numbers.  'john, suzan, jack, erin, adan' are first names, etc.. However, the only issue I ran into is when I'm trying to print the array of grades, ex: '88, 79, 59' into an `ArrayList` object that prints: 887959(1 arraylist object), NOT 88 (1 arraylist object), 79(another arraylist object),...

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Code:

```
String[] kaizer = 
        {

            "1,John,Smith,John1989@gmail.com,20,88,79,59",
            "2,Suzan,Erickson,Erickson_1990@gmailcom,19,91,72,85",
            "3,Jack,Napoli,The_lawyer99yahoo.com,19,85,84,87",
            "4,Erin,Black,Erin.black@comcast.net,22,91,98,82",
            "5,Adan,Ramirez,networkturple66@gmail.com,23,100,100,100"
        };
ArrayList<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < kaizer.length; i++) {
    String s = kaizer[i]; //volatile reference
    String[] parts = s.split(","); 
    //volatile reference
    String id = parts[0];
    String name = parts[1];
    String lastname = parts[2];
    String email = parts[3];
    String age = parts[4];
    grades.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[5])); 
    grades.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[6]));
    grades.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[7]));
    //Widget w = new Widget(id, name, num);
    //mywidgets.add(w);
}
```

This is supposed to print the set of substrings like this:

```
887959 
917285
858487
919882
100100100

System.out.println(grades.get(0)); 
System.out.println(grades.get(1));
System.out.println(grades.get(2));
System.out.println(grades.get(3));
System.out.println(grades.get(4));
```

Instead... it prints:

```
8879599172
```

The problem lies in the output: '8879599172'

Comment: Since you're working with Java, I think you should try to solve this problem using OOP.

Comment: You need 1 grades array per for loop. Maybe a hashmap<int, ArrayList<Integer>>, where the key is id and value the grades for this id.

Comment: @DaniloSilva or just use a `List<Student>` where the `Student` data is obtained after parsing each `String`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Unfortunately OP might not know what it means.  Many courses teach procedural programming in Java, sometimes using `main()` as the only method.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, I think this is the better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grades` is an `ArrayList` and as far as it's concerned you are just adding Integers to it. It doesn't know when it's supposed to break. Index `3` is just the `Integer` after index `2`. If you want to combine each one into combined values you can do `grades.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[5]+parts[6]+parts[7]))` or you can insert a line break after each 3 values added to `grades`. You can also make a `grades` a `List` with sublists that are each a `List` of type `Integer`.

Comment: BINGO! you got it! in just a few minutes you saved me from killing myself, gj!

Answer (score 0):

You are storing all the values in a 1-dimensional ArrayList, in your scenario, you should consider using a 2-dimensional ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> grades = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < kaizer.length; i++) {
    String s = kaizer[i]; //volatile reference
    String[] parts = s.split(","); 
    //volatile reference
    String id = parts[0];
    String name = parts[1];
    String lastname = parts[2];
    String email = parts[3];
    String age = parts[4];

    ArrayList<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    subList.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[5])); 
    subList.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[6]));
    subList.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[7]));
    grades.add(i, subList);

    //Widget w = new Widget(id, name, num);
    //mywidgets.add(w);
}
```

Then, you can loop through the grades for each student:

```
//for each student
for(ArrayList<Integer> list : grades)
{
    for(int grade : list)
    {
        //do something with each grade
    }
}
```